# Relation field query not working as expected

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, many-to-many

I have an Event table and it has a column called "attendees" which is a Relation type to _User [many to many].

I have tried the following to get a list of all _Users who are attending an Event based on the objectId for the event. In my code below the success and error callbacks are *not* being called. (Neither SUCCESS or ERROR is being printed to the error log.)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("cancelEvent", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
    query.get(request.params.eventId, {
        success: function(event) {
            // event.set("status", "cancelled");
            // event.save();

            // notify attendees of cancellation
            var relation = event.relation("attendees");
            var innerQuery = relation.query();
            innerQuery.find({
                success: function(attendees) {
                    console.error("SUCCESS");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.error("ERROR");
                }
            });

            event.save();
            response.success();
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.error("Failed to cancel event.");
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move             event.save();
            response.success();
to inside the success callback like this

```
Parse.Cloud.define("cancelEvent", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Event");
    query.get(request.params.eventId, {
        success: function(event) {
            // event.set("status", "cancelled");
            // event.save();

            // notify attendees of cancellation
            var relation = event.relation("attendees");
            var innerQuery = relation.query();
            innerQuery.find({
                success: function(attendees) {
                    console.error("SUCCESS");

            event.save();
            response.success();

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.error("ERROR");
                }
            });

        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.error("Failed to cancel event.");
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```